# Error set up Azure CosmosEmulator in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am following the steps in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cosmos-db
to connect my spring project to Azure cosmosDB Emulator

I have the emulator running locally
[image]

However I am running in to

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.data.cosmos.CosmosClient]: Factory method 'cosmosClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider.fixed(Ljava/lang/String;IJLjava/time/Duration;)Lreactor/netty/resources/ConnectionProvider; (loaded from file:/Users/yatman.wong/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty-core/1.0.15/reactor-netty-core-1.0.15.jar by jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@b0c88fd9) called from interface com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.http.HttpClient (loaded from file:/Users/yatman.wong/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-cosmos/3.7.3/azure-cosmos-3.7.3.jar by jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@b0c88fd9).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
```

Looks like some internal dependency issue with this azure dependency

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-data-cosmosdb</artifactId> 
    <version>2.3.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

I have set up a bug demo project in https://github.com/yatw/SpringCosmosEmulator with full stack trace

Please give me an explanation, thank you!

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: nope, kinda droped this service, but you can follow this thread https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/17866#issuecomment-1039932958